# Why are dot products scalar, intuitively?

Tags: vectors

Why are dot products scalar (in the general sense) if seen from an intuitive point of view ? i am not asking about a particular case like kinetic energy or work but a i want the answer for general dot products

Comment: and also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107089/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111866/

Comment: Because we wanted a scalar value.

Comment: You should note that this is a defintion.